# How to disable LDAP server in WSO2 ESB 4.0.3

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We are trying to pass the Information Security review of our WSO2 ESB implementation. Looks like they do not like LDAP server being listening on the 10389.

Is there way to Disable LDAP server which starts by defualt when WSO2 ESB is started?

I found "embedded-ldap.xml" file in conf directory and there is switch enable LDAP but when I set "enable" property to false I start getting errors about User mgmt.

Is thee a clean way to remove the LDAP and USer management from WSO2 4.0.3?

thanks
Abhijit

Answer (score 0):

LDAP is used for usermanagement. You can disable LDAP usermanagement configuration in the user-mgt.xml, and use  JDBC user store. Enable following section in your user-mgt.xml.

```
<!--UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager">
    <Property name="ReadOnly">false</Property>
        <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
        <Property name="IsEmailUserName">false</Property>
        <Property name="DomainCalculation">default</Property>
        <Property name="PasswordDigest">SHA-256</Property>
        <Property name="StoreSaltedPassword">true</Property>
        <Property name="UserNameUniqueAcrossTenants">false</Property>
        <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">[\\S]{5,30}</Property>
    <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">^[^~!@#$;%^*+={}\\|\\\\&lt;&gt;]{3,30}$</Property>
    <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">[\\S]{3,30}</Property>
    <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">^[^~!@#$;%^*+={}\\|\\\\&lt;&gt;]{3,30}$</Property>
    <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">[\\S]{3,30}</Property>
        <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
    </UserStoreManager-->
```